# How can I make a QGroupBox with a title that is two lines?

Tags: qt

I tried using a string with a \n embedded in between the two lines, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Newline character seems to work:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QGroupBox gb("This is the first line\nAnd this is line 2\nAnd 3");
    gb.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Get me this on Mac with both Qt 4.8 and Qt 5:

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me.  Is there some parameter that I haven't set?

Comment: QString title="Confidence:"+QString::number(confidence*100,'f',1)+"\n"+"Matches:"+QString::number(matches);groupBox->setTitle(title);

Comment: By the way, QString::arg() is generally much easier to use than QString::number()

Comment: Well. It works for me. See my edit. But I really don't like the effect. You probably better off use something else. Like a QFrame with a QLable, for example.